# find_or_create not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a very simple app. All this app needs to do is check if a username exists. If if does, redirect to the user. If it does not exist, create a new user as per the username entered and redirect to the new user. New users never get created for some reason but the find_or_create line works in rails console. Here is the code:

user_controller.rb

```
  def new

    @user = User.new

  end


  def create

    @u = User.find_or_create_by_name(params[:name])
    redirect_to @u

  end
```

new.html.erb

```
<% form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :Username %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your application? If it's not creating the user, you should get an error on that redirect. If it is, you should be getting an error when saving to the database fails. Also, make sure that your application is running with this code in place; a restart will quash any doubts.

Comment: a name is all a user needs to be created? no other validations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails is going to package the whole form within `params[:user]`, so you really want `params[:user][:name]`

That is:

```
@u = User.find_or_create_by_name(params[:user][:name])
```

Comment: Jeez, I was wondering if params might be a hash but decided it wouldn't be. Facepalm. Works like a charm, thanks!